# use RANK or DENSE_RANK along with aggregate function

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions, rank, dense-rank, partition-by

I have a table  with the following data:

```
SCORE    ROW_ID   NAME
0.4      1011    ABC
0.95     1011    DEF
0.4      501     GHI
0.95     501     XYZ
```

At any point of time, i only need single row of data with maximum score, if there has more than 1 records, take the one with minimum row_id.

Is it possible to achieve by using `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` function? How about partition by?

```
MAX(score) keep(dense_rank first order by row_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for max score, one row, so use row_number():

```
select score, row_id, name
  from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by score desc, row_id) rn from t)
  where rn = 1
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=45f08dc0d3776c9a19db522a4f418f20)</sup>**

You can use `rank` and `dense_rank` in your example, but they can return more than one row, for instance when you add row `(0.95,  501, 'PQR')` to your data.

---

`keep dense_rank` is typically used when searched value is **other** than search criteria, for instance if we look for salary of employee who works the longest:

```
max(salary) keep (dense_rank first order by sysdate - hiredate desc)
```

`max` in this case means that if there are two or more employees who works longest, but exactly the same number of days than we take highest salary.

```
max(salary) 
  keep (dense_rank first order by sysdate - hiredate desc) 
  over (partition by deptno)
```

This is the same as above, but salary of longest working employees is shown for each department separately. You can even use empty `over()` to show salary of longest working employee in separate column except other data like name, salary, hire_date.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works, appreciate of your explanation on dense_rank :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use dense_rank. This would help

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    SCORE,
    ROW_ID
    NAME 
  FROM T
  ORDER BY SCORE DESC, ROW_ID DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```